# general way of handling multiple facebook like buttons

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

i'm working on a website that has a lot of products (think grocery list) and each one has a facebook like button associated with it.

currently we are loading each like button on the load of the page. I am working to re-write this so we only load the like button when the user hovers over each product. and we just stick a dummy button with each element on first load.

my question is this a standard way of handeling multiple facebook like buttons?

and are there other ways of doing this?

and i'm looking for other websites with over 100 facebook like buttons on a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just for aesthetic, load them all, but with a CSS style of `display: none;`. When they hover over the element, you can either use CSS :hover in a parent `<a>` element to make them visible, or just use javascript/JQuery to change the CSS to `display: block;` or whatever on mouseover, and back to `display: none;` on mouse out.

Comment: i was looking for other examples but this answers the technical side of the question. Thanks!!